# Category attribute does not work on PropertyGrid

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

I have class, which must display on PropertyGrid(from WPF Toolkit)

```
 public class VertexProperties
{
    private readonly Point2DU _vertex;
    private readonly ChainViewModel _chainViewModel;
    private readonly F2d _segment;
    [Category("Vertex")]
    public double X
    {
        get { return _vertex.X; }
        set
        {
            _vertex.X = value;
            _chainViewModel.RefreshAll();
        }
    }
    [Category("Vertex")]
    public double Y
    {

        get { return _vertex.Y; }
        set
        {
            _vertex.Y = value;
            _chainViewModel.RefreshAll();
        }
    }
    public VertexProperties( Point2DU vertex, ChainViewModel chainViewModel, F2d segment)
    {
        _vertex = vertex;
        _chainViewModel = chainViewModel;
        _segment = segment;
    }
}
```

But category not appears in PropertyGrid. However, DisplayName Attribute works properly.

[image: Pic]

Comment: Can you provide a sample project with both the XAML and code demonstrating this or has this question died?

Answer (score 0):

SamTheDev's answer is not accurate as the Vetex object is readonly, not the internal properties of it.  Have you made sure that the PropertyGrid is using categories:

`<xctk:PropertyGrid IsCategorized="True" AutoGenerateProperties="True" />`

I believe that the grid should be categorized by default.  Can you show the XAML / Code behind that you are using?